# Expected visibility

Tags: ambient-occlusion, ray

I want to extend the following to work on a solid angle:

Suppose we have a volume filled with small surfaces.  If we cast a ray from a given point, the probability that the ray will not hit a surface (i.e. is visible to the sky) is given as

$P(ray\ does\ not\ hit) = {e}^{-\alpha d/\cos\theta}$

where $\alpha$ is some decay factor, $d/cos\theta$ is the path length of the ray within the volume.

**My question:**
 How can we compute the expected visibility of a ray if we consider the directions $(\theta, \phi)$, where $0<\theta<\pi/2$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$?

Comment: What do you mean by "consider the directions"? Are you trying to integrate over some solid angle instead of a single ray? Are you trying to extend the volume to be heterogeneous or anisotropic?

Comment: I am integrating over some solid angle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform integration of $P$ over the hemisphere to [calculate the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-alpha%2FCos%5Btheta%5D%5D*sin%5Btheta%5D,%20%7Btheta,%200,%20pi%2F2%7D,%20%7Bphi,%200,%202pi%7D%5D). There doesn't seem to be closed-form solution as the solution requires [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function):
$$2\pi(e^{-\alpha d}-\alpha d\Gamma(0,\alpha d))$$